# Existence of a map between curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given two algebraic curves defined over the rationals, is there a method for determining whether there exists a surjective map from one curve to the other? For instance, suppose X and Y are affine plane curves. How to tell whether there is a dominant rational map X->Y?

Comment: What data are you putting in? Degrees of the polynomials defining is not intrinsic, since change of variables can make the degrees very different.

Comment: I am assuming that equations for X and Y are given.

Comment: I think this is too little to say anything. Theoretically, the equations do define curves, but little can be deduced apriori about them.

Comment: Using the equation, one could compute the zeta functions of the curves over some finite fields and check that the numerator of $\zeta(Y)$ divides the numerator of $\zeta(X)$. That's a necessary condition.

Comment: If $g(Y) \geq 2$ then the degree of such a map is bounded so this can be expressed as a first-order statement in the theory of algebraically closed fields, hence can be solved at the very least using Tarski's quantifier elimination algorithm. If you want a more efficient algorithm, look into what computer algebra systems can do. If $g(Y)=0$ the answer is always yes and I'm not sure what to do in the genus $1$ case but I'm sure it's fine.

Comment: If you want the map to be also defined over the rationals then you're probably going to be in trouble though -- for example I think that there's no algorithm which provably terminates which tells you whether a curve of genus 1 has a rational point.